# How to suppress inclusion of source code in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

Is there a flag that prevents doxygen from generating a pretty printed copy of the source (i.e. header) file? I just need the actual documentation and not the link to the actual file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, make sure that

```
SOURCE_BROWSER   = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS = NO
```

in the configuration file.